# How to bound view margin to viewmodel string live data?

Tags: kotlin, margin, mutablelivedata

Current issue is a bit complicated, so I will outline some words with "" so whoever reads this could be able to understand text below.

I have a "page viewer", which implements "recycler view adapter".
Each page has 4 textviews inside it, i pass text to "adapter" through "constructor parameter".
My goal is to get position of textviews (filled with text), and use it to set margin to views in main fragment (which contains page viewer).

I tried to do it with help of "view model live data", so i passed setters for "view model strings live data" as "lambda" to "recycler view adapter" and I tried to "set text" and "get position" for "strings live data" in onBindViewHolder fun. Here is the adapter:

```
class PagerAdapter(private val spannableStrings: List<List<SpannableStringBuilder>>, 
val liveDataSetters: List<(Int)->Unit>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PagerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

var location1 = IntArray(2)
var location2 = IntArray(2)
var location3 = IntArray(2)
var location4 = IntArray(2)

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var textView1: TextView? = null
    var textView2: TextView? = null
    var textView3: TextView? = null
    var textView4: TextView? = null

    init {
        textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview1)
        textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview2)
        textView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview3)
        textView4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview4)

    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder =
    ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false))


override fun getItemCount(): Int = spannableStrings.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    if (position==0) {

        holder.textView1?.text = spannableStrings[0][0]
        holder.textView2?.text = spannableStrings[0][1]
        holder.textView3?.text = spannableStrings[0][2]
        holder.textView4?.text = spannableStrings[0][3]

        holder.textView1?.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
        liveDataSetters[0](location1[1])

        holder.textView2?.getLocationOnScreen(location2)
        liveDataSetters[1](location2[1])

        holder.textView3?.getLocationOnScreen(location3)
        liveDataSetters[2](location3[1])

        holder.textView4?.getLocationOnScreen(location4)
        liveDataSetters[3](location4[1])


    }

    else {
        holder.textView1?.text = spannableStrings[1][0]
        holder.textView2?.text = spannableStrings[1][1]
        holder.textView3?.text = ""
        holder.textView4?.text = ""

        holder.textView1?.getLocationOnScreen(location1)
        liveDataSetters[0](location1[0])

        holder.textView2?.getLocationOnScreen(location2)
        liveDataSetters[1](location2[0])
    }

}

}
```

Here is code snippet regarding this from main fragment:

```
binding.viewpager2.adapter= activity?.let {
                PagerAdapter(listOf(
                    listOf(text1a, text2a, text3a, text4a), listOf(text1b, text2b)
                ),
                    listOf(viewModel.setLocation1, viewModel.setLocation2, viewModel.setLocation3, viewModel.setLocation4)
                )
            }




            TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewpager2) { tab, position ->
            }.attach()
```

Code snippet from view model:

```
private var _location1 = MutableLiveData<String>()
val location1:  LiveData<String> = _location1

val setLocation1: (Int) -> Unit = { value -> location1.value=value.toString()+"dp"}
...
```

And finally xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.project.ui.main.view.viewModel" />
</data>

...

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pointer1a"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@{viewModel.location1}"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

...
```

However, what i recieve on launch is:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.project.databinding.FragmentBindingImpl;
```

As far as i understand, no live data could be passed to xml margin top parameter, because whenever i set this data to, let's say, random textview as text, everythin works fine. How can i solve this case? Maybe there are any alternatives or workarounds that i am missing?